# Using json.loads v/s yajl.loads for reading a large JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, yajl

I am working with huge JSON files, with size ranging from 100-300 MB. Hence in order to save disk space (and computation time?), I converted the JSON file into a `.json.gz` file and proceeded like this :

```
with gzip.GzipFile(json_file, 'r') as f:
    return json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

`json.loads` didn't cause any issues with memory usage, but I would like to increase the speed, and hence I tried `py-yajl` (not to be confused with [yajl-py](http://pykler.github.io/yajl-py/), which I tried as well, but that took much more time since I was parsing the streamed JSON), like this :

```
yajl.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

But as I have seen on sites claiming that `yajl` is faster than `json` and `simplejson` libraries, I couldn't see an improvement in execution time. On the contrary, it took a bit more time as compared to `json`. Am I missing something here? In what cases, `yajl` is supposed to be faster than `json/simplejson`? Does the speed depend on the structure of a JSON file as well?

My JSON file looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "bytes_sent": XXX,
        "forwardedfor": "-",
        "hostip": "XXX",
        "hostname": "XXX",
        "https": "on",
        "landscapeName": "XXX",
    },
    ...
]
```

I am aware that this is a subjective question and is likely to be closed,  but I couldn't clear my doubts anywhere, and, at the same time, I would like to know about the difference b/w these libraries in more detail, hence asking here.

Comment: `yajl.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))` != `gzip.GzipFile(json_file, 'r').read().decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading the entire structure into memory at once anyway, the external library offers no benefits. The motivation for a tool like that is that it allows you to process things piecemeal, without having to load the entire thing into memory first, or at all. If your JSON is a list of things, process one thing at a time, via the callbacks the library offers.

Comment: My JSON is a list of objects actually, like I posted in the question above. I tried streaming this JSON using `yajl-py` library and making appropriate callback methods for to handle data inside objects, but it didn't speed up the process. I am looking to actually speed up, with memory usage being second priority.

Comment: The `f.read()` already loads the entire thing into memory. You want to give the library a file handle and let it consume it as it goes. This is all in the documentation (which I read for the first time some three minutes ago).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Slipped out of my mind, that one. But the thing is, it's a gzip file. How to proceed in that case?

Comment: The `with` in your question shows exactly how to open a file handle for reading as `gz`.

Comment: It still didn't help. I even tried [this](https://pastebin.com/vUqY1bFJ). Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Not really in a place where I can test that.  The `pass` statements certainly look superfluous, but that's inconsequential. Maybe accept this answer (or post one of your own and accept that if you prefer) and ask a new question with your actual code (including `import`s) and enough data to repro? See also the guidance for creating a [mcve].